# How to identify unique columns in a data frame with respect to other data frames?

Tags: r

If I have several data frames, how can I identify the columns which are unique to a certain data frame?

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=rnorm(5), B=rnorm(5), C=rnorm(5))
df2 <- data.frame(B=rnorm(5), C=rnorm(5), D=rnorm(5))
df3 <- data.frame(B=rnorm(5), C=rnorm(5), D=rnorm(5))
```

What I want to achieve is something like the unique() function, that gives me the unique columns in a data frame with respect to other data frames.

```
unique.columns(df1, c(df2, df3))
[1] "A"
```

but

```
unique.columns(df2, c(df1, df3))
[1] NA
```

since there are no unique columns in df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` and `union`

```
unique.columns <- function(df1, df2, df3) {
   setdiff(names(df1), union(names(df2), names(df3)))
}

unique.columns(df1, df2, df3)
#[1] "A"

unique.columns(df2, df1, df3)
#character(0)
```

---

If you are going to pass a variable number of dataframes to the function, you can change the function

```
unique.columns <- function(df1, ...) {
   temp <- list(...)
   setdiff(names(df1), unique(c(sapply(temp, names))))
}

unique.columns(df1, df3)
#[1] "A"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Reduce` along with `setdiff` to deal with any number of comparison datasets easily. The first named dataset will be compared to the remainder.

```
Reduce(setdiff, lapply(list(df1,df2,df3), names))
#[1] "A"

Reduce(setdiff, lapply(list(df2,df1,df3), names))
#character(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the "not in" using `!` and `%in%` on the `colnames` of each df to get the column names that are unique to one df in comparison with other dfs.

```
colnames(df1)[!(colnames(df1) %in% c(colnames(df2),colnames(df3)))]
#[1] "A"
colnames(df2)[!(colnames(df2) %in% c(colnames(df1),colnames(df3)))]
#character(0)
```